# Laravel: Retrieving table results by category name instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have this relationship between products and productcategories, one product belongs to a category and a category can hold many products, problem is I want to retrieve all products belonging to a productcategory by name instead of using id.

Something similary looking to this??

```js
public function index()
    {
        Product::where(productcategory->name, 'Starters')->get();
    }
```

These are my migrations:

```js
//CREATE PRODUCTS TABLE
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('productcategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('productcategory_id')->references('id')->on('productcategories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('available')->default(true);
            $table->string('half');
            $table->string('full');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        
        
        
        
        //CREATE PRODUCT CATEGORIES TABLE
        Schema::create('productcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        DB::table('productcategories')->insert([
            'name' => 'Starters'),
        ]);
        DB::table('productcategories')->insert([
            'name' => 'Salads'),
        ]);
        DB::table('productcategories')->insert([
            'name' => 'Soups'),
        ]);
```

And my models:

```js
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productcategories';
    
    
    
    
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

```js
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    
    
    
    
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }
    
    
    
    
    public function productcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory');
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the product category and get its products:

```
$products = ProductCategory::where('name', 'Starters')->first()->products;
```

Or use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$products = Product::whereHas('productcategory', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Starters');
})->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?